# User defined Function works in Route::get() but not Route::group()

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am using laravel 7 and created a function to include all route files `includeRouteFiles()` in a directory. Im just trying to figure out why this works:

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
        includeRouteFiles(__DIR__ . '/someFolder/');
    });
```

and this does not:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'SomeSpace'], function() {
     includeRouteFiles(__DIR__ . '/someFolder/');
});
```

this is located in the web.php file under the routes directory.

I assume the that the code in the ServiceProvider where the functions lives is correct because it works in `Route::get()`.

thank you

Comment: yeah, group takes a closure that contains Routes. What exactly are you trying to do on all these grouped routes, maybe it can be moved to a middleware?

Comment: Check [App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php) file and conclude how you can set that easier. You can use example similarly how web routes are included.

Comment: I was trying to avoid always having to add `mapSomeRoute() inside the RouteServiceProvider. The function get get all files in the web directory and requires them. So that i can just add a new route file and have it automatically added by way of the Service Provider.

Comment: @UzairRiaz So all the routes in this particular group are for a backend that will only have access for user s with that permission. I just wanted to segment the routes into individual files relating to the same parts/

Comment: did you try changing `['namespace' => 'someFolder']`?